# If astronomers didn't know about redshift could we still determine the universe is expanding?

Tags: general-relativity, expansion, redshift, special-relativity

What other evidence is there for the expansion of the universe?
Would the equations of physics look wrong without it?

Comment: Why would redshift not be known? The (varied) reasons have many knock-on implications.

Comment: This is rather like asking "if scientists didn't know about 'falling' could we still determine a theory of gravity"

Comment: Yeah , if redshift isn't known, then the astronomers don't know how to measure the speed of light, or it's infinite and astronomers are disintegrated by Olber's paradox.

Comment: The density rises as you look far away.  Distance would come from other methods.  Cluster distances and densities could do it.  Eventually, enough galaxies will have an SN1a measurement.

Comment: I would think that electrons protons etc from supernovae explosions would have less energy than predicted by theory That would be a good indicator of  Hubble expansion.

Comment: Given the technological and knowledge requirements to measure distances and velocities in the universe of the other methods, it does not sound reasonable to assume that spectroscopy is unavailable - especially as imaging and taking spectra are some of the most direct methods to obtain data.